# The argument type 'File?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'

Tags: flutter, flutter-file

After I do pub upgrade,
The error says "The argument type 'File?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'."

Maybe it is because

<await imagesMedia! .where((element) => element.id == id) .first .getFile()> is type 'File?'

But I'm not sure how can I change this.

```
                      await Future.forEach(selectedImagesIDs!,
                          (String id) async {
                        selectedFiles.add(await imagesMedia!
                            .where((element) => element.id == id)
                            .first
                            .getFile());
```

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File?` means that this object can be either `File` or `null`, while the `File` type can't be `null` and it will throw an error if you try to make it `null`. To solve your problem you can either change type of the parameter of your function (the function where you pass data from this `Future`) from `File` to `File?` or if you can guarantee that `.getFile()` won't ever return `null`, you can put an `bang` operator `(!)` after your function call like this:

```
 selectedFiles.add(await imagesMedia!
                            .where((element) => element.id == id)
                            .first
                            .getFile())!;
```